# Search file for characters excluding a set of characters

Tags: unix

I have a text file with 1.3million rows and 258 columns delimited by semicolons (;). How can I search for what characters are in the file, excluding letters of the alphabet (both upper and lower case), semicolon (;), quote (') and double quote (")? Ideally the results should be in a non-duplicated list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pipeline

```
# Remove the characters you want to exclude
tr -d 'A-Za-z;"'\' <file |
# One character on each line
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\
/g' | 
# Remove duplicates
sort -u
```

Example

```
echo '2343abc34;ABC;;@$%"' | 
tr -d 'A-Za-z;"'\' |
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\
/g' | 
sort -u

$
%
2
3
4
@
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use grep -v command and pipe it to sort and then to uniq.